# Error while compiling: expected expression before ')' token

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, c-preprocessor

This is one of the conditions in my program:

```
if(Debug)fprintf(stdout,"Direction dir %d quot %d rem %0.2f %s\n",direction,quotient, remain, cardinal[quotient]);
```

I have defined everything  and have used `stdlib.h` but it keeps returning

```
expected expression before ')' token
```

I use minGW compiler in ECLIPSE. Compiled as follows: `gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o wind_direction.o "..\\wind_direction.c"`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please format your code, and tag your questions correctly.

Comment: #define Debug        only, I guess

Comment: Try splitting it over several lines (so you can tell whether it is the `if` or the `fprintf()` giving trouble).  Try cutting it down to about 5 lines of code plus headers.  Try removing arguments from the `fprintf()` call.  Try compiling with the `-E` or `-P` options to get the preprocessor output and look at the actual text that's causing trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably you have:

```
#define Debug
```

With is good for conditional compilation:

```
#ifdef Debug
...
#endif
```

But the if need an expression inside the (). Use, for example:

```
#define Debug 1
```

if you want to print, and `0` if you dont want. (but now use `#if Debug` for conditional compilation)